# Autolayout bottom spacing constraint is not obeyed

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have a UIButton and a UILabel **constrained to be a standard distance from the bottom of the Superview**. Works well on the iPad, but on the smaller iPhone screens, when other elements take up too much space, these views are pushed off the edge of the screen despite their constraint to remain a standard distance from the bottom. Why is this so?

What I would like to have happen is for the four rectangles to shrink in size so that there is still room for the "Go Back" and "Question" label to remain a standard distance from the bottom. The four rectangles can maintain aspect ratio and equal width/height by all shrinking at the same ratio. I have no constraints on their needing to be equal to or larger than a certain size. I've tried lowering their Content Compression Resistance Priority as well.

Configuration:

[image: AutoLayout Explanation]

(I have also tried "equal" and "<=" in top spacing between "Go Back" & bottom left rectangle)
("Greater than or equal" works best on iPad to keep "Go Back" at the bottom of the screen)

**How it looks on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ - with the labels cut off at bottom:**
[image: AutoLayout on Device]

Comment: Your horizontal constraints from the left edge through the views to the right edge essentially, gives them a fixed width (relative to any seen size), and the aspect ratio then fixes the hight.

Comment: But what if the horizontal constraints on left edge and right edge are also set to >= the standard spacing distance, which should allow them to shrink...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to lower those four buttons' height constraint's priority??
For example like this, try to set them to 750

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. These buttons do not have any height constraints, they are just set to equal width and height as the other buttons but without a required size

Comment: so your didn't add any height constraint to any element on the view?? if your didn't add the height width constraint, the auto layout may not work

Comment: if you don't mind, you can create a simple project with this view setup in the storyboard file, and share it to me. I can help you to look into it :D

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work with a couple of changes and additions. Give the leading and trailing constraints between the top 2 rectangles and the superview a lower priority (I used 749), but still keep them as "equal". This will keep them at the standard distance from the edges if it's possible, but will allow them to have a larger spacing if the vertical space combined with the aspect ratio requires it. The problem with this, is that since they aren't required any more, when those constraints need to stretch, there's nothing that says they have to stretch equally; therefore, we need some way to keep the rectangles centered. So, instead of a spacing constraint between the left and right top rectangles, add a small view (I used 8x8) that has a centerY constraint to one of the rectangles, and zero constant spacing constraints to the two rectangles. Give this view a centerX constraint to the superview; this construct will give you the same spacing between your rectangles that you had before, but will keep them centered in the superview while allowing them to shrink in width (and height to keep the aspect ratio) if need to accommodate the vertical space.

Comment: Good suggestion on using a small view centered to keep two items to either side of it centered (this seems much simpler than using two hidden views on the edges as shown in CS 193P and other tutorials).

Comment: Still mostly touch & go/trial & error for me trying to get auto layout scenes looking "close to right" on every device. More often than wanted I end up creating different constants for regular height size classes vs compact height to get the constraints to act properly across the different devices.